# Using JSON to store entity stats within a game

Tags: json

I'm planning to create a game, either Turn Based Strategy or a Fantasy RPG and an idea I thought of was to use [json](/questions/tagged/json)to store the stats of the player and any computer entities within. I've never used [json](/questions/tagged/json)before but it looks pretty simple, So i'm wondering if this would good idea to use it or to use database to hold the information?

Comment: JSON is cool when you are transferring data from A to B, if you are creating a game and need to store data locally, you want to use a regular database structure

Comment: Yes, it's good.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to think ahead.
You should build a database to store game information.
And you could use JSON to exchange game data on a network.
You would have many possibilities under this concept. For instance:
You would display the information of your game, which is stored in your database in a Web page, using JSON format.

I hope this helps you.